# Get the FIrst character from the Firstname if more than one firstname is present in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g, oracle-data-integrator

I have a requirement where the persons can have more than one first name and i need to convert the name into first characters from the 2 or more names with capital letters.

Examples:

```
Srinivas Kalyan ,Sai Kishore
```

if the above is one having 4 first names then  i need to display as below

```
S K S K
```

The comma is also be replaced and take all the first characters

```
2. Srinivas-Kalyan Sai Kishore
```

For the above name the value should be as

```
S S K
```

since Srinivas-Kalyan is considered as one name

Also the name can be in small letters

```
srinivas kalyan sai kishore
```

For this

```
S K S K
```

This has to be in oracle

Tried the below regex_replace which is working fine in sql developer but in the application it is changing into space

```
replace(trim(regexp_replace(to_char(regexp_replace(initcap(regexp_replace(regexp_replace
(FIRST_NAME, '[0-9]', ''), '( *[[:punct:]])', '')), '([[:lower:]]| )')), '(.)', '\1 ')),',',null)
```

Comment: Which application are you talking about, when you say "it is changing to space" ?

Comment: ODI Developer where i am getting the \1 as space

Answer (score 2):

The missing letter in your output is caused by this regex for character removal:

```
( *[[:punct:]])
```

This will turn `Kalyan ,Sai` into `KalyanSai`, which will be treated as one word by the rest of the process, and so you will not have the S of Sai in your output.

I would suggest this shorter expression:

```
trim(upper(regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace(first_name, '([[:alpha:]])(-|[[:alpha:]])+', '\1'),
    '.*?([[:alpha:]]|$)', ' \1'
)))
```

#### Explanation

1. `([[:alpha:]])(-|[[:alpha:]])+` -> `\1`

   This replaces any sequence of letters (or hyphen) with the first of those. So it reduces words to their initial letter.
2. `.*?([[:alpha:]]|$)` -> `(space)\1`

   This replaces anything that precedes the next letter, with a space. As no letter will be skipped (because `.*?` is non-greedy) this effectively replaces all non-letter sequences with a space. To also replace the non-letters at the very end (which do not precede a letter), the special case `$` (end-of-string) is added as alternative.

After these two steps there just remains to:

- Upper case everything
- Remove blanks at the start and end of the result with `trim`

I find the advantage of this method is that it does not use any other class than `[[:alpha]]`. Digits, punctuation, lowercase -- or whatever else -- does not need to be identified explicitly, as it is just the negation of `[[:alpha]]`. The only exception that has to be made, is for the hyphen.

As some names might include some other non-letters, like a quote, you might want to add such characters as well in the first regular expression.

Comment: can you check for this string      Fusion276-Deepu Raghava Pradeep as this is giving F D R P but the expected is F R P

Comment: Are digits part of a name? That is really strange! Then can an initial be a digit too? Anyway I explained how to do this in my last paragraph. In this case change in regex1 `(-|[[:alpha:]])` by `(-|[[:alnum:]])`